# Cannot import C++ Boost.Python class/library in python

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have my C++ class set up as follows:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "Python.h"

namespace something
{
namespace other
{

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(classname)
{
    method_call_in_other_file();
}
```

The method call is in another file:

```
namespace something
{
namespace other
{

namespace python = boost::python;

void method_call_in_other_file()
{
    //doing stuff
}
```

Makefile is as follows:

```
X86CPPTARGETSOL += libSOMETHING.cpp.so
libSOMETHING.cpp.so,SRCS = \
      CPP_FILE_ONE.cpp \
      CPP_FILE_TWO.cpp
libSOMETHING.cpp.so,DEPSOL = \
      libpython2.7 \
      libboost_python \
      libOTHER_DEPENDENCIES
```

The library is correctly built in my lib folder at lib/libSOMETHING.cpp.so.
I start python from the same directory the lib folder is in, then I append lib/ to the path:
`sys.path.append('./lib')`

Now when I try to import my boost_python_module (as seen in the quickstart here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html#tutorial.quickstart)

it cannot find the module:

```
>>> import classname
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named classname
```

I also tried importing the lib files directly:

```
>>> import libSOMETHING
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libSOMETHING
>>> import libSOMETHING.cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libSOMETHING.cpp
>>> import libSOMETHING.cpp.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named libSOMETHING.cpp.so
```

Using `help('modules')` to list available modules also doesn't show anything that could resemble this required import.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found the answer: the `*.so` file needs to be named exactly like `classname` in `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(classname)`. Symlinking works too. So I created a symlink from `libSOMETHING.cpp.so` to `classname.so` and now it works fine.